# Coldfusion - HTTPS error / X.509 ws-security

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, https, coldfusion

I'm very new to SOAP, and this is my first project. I am trying to connect to a HTTPS WSDL in order to pull some information on my webpage.

There is a certificate setup ready for both local server connect with the service provider server. There is a response when I try to connect the https webservice, so I believe there is no connection issue between both server :

[image: HTTPs Webservice connection response]

Here is the SOAPUI sample given from the third party technical team :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:soap="http://soap.ipr.tfp.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <soap:create>
          <arg0>
            <attribute_1>abc</attribute_1>
            <attribute_2></attribute_2>
            <attribute_3>abc123</attribute_3>
            <attribute_4>abc234</attribute_4>
            <attribute_5></attribute_5>
          </arg0>
       </soap:create>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is my cfm code used to connect the Webservice :

```
<cfscript>
    ws = CreateObject("webservice", [HTTPS URL]?wsdl);
    //show web service methods for debugging purposes
    writeDump(ws);

    // construct arguments
    args = {attribute_1="abc"
            , attribute_2=""
            , attribute_3="abc123"
            , attribute_4="abc234"
            , attribute_5=""
        };
    // call the method
    result  = ws.create(arg0=args);

    writeDump(result)
</cfscript>
```

**Issue :**

I'm getting below error message when execute my cfm script :

```
     Cannot perform web service invocation create.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not SIGNED
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EncryptedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not ENCRY...
```

**Questions :**

1. Is this error related to the SSL certificate setup in the ColdFusion keystore?
2. Anything wrong with my CFM script? Refer to the SOAPUI sample, the xml format is `[arg0] --> [attribute_1], [attribute_2] and so on. Can I pass the attributes this way?

   - *result  = ws.create(arg0=args);*
3. The same service works from SoapUI tool. Am I missing anything here?

Thank you for your time. Your help is appreciated.

**2016-05-30 - Update -**

I tried to use the `CFHTTP` tag to submit the XML, but it seemed to return a differenct error:

```
<cfhttp
    url     = "[HTTPS URL]?wsdl"
    method  ="post"
    result  ="httpResponse" 
    charset ="utf-8">

    <cfhttpparam
        type="header"
        name="accept-encoding"
        value="no-compression"
    />
    <cfhttpparam
        type="xml"
        value="#trim( soapBody )#"
        />
</cfhttp>
```

**Error:**

[image: Error Message Image]

Here is the error message in the file content :

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            X509Token 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            InitiatorToken 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            RecipientToken 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            SignedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
            Body not SIGNED 
            {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}
            EncryptedParts: 
            {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
            Body not ENCRYPTED
            </faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The error message seems similar to `cfobject` tag. When I read closely in the error message, it seemed related with the X.509 ws-security encryption where the SOAP content needs to encrypted before send to the Web service request.

After did some research, the encryption flow seem work as below:

1. Save SOAP content into temp folder.
2. Used Java Class file to encrypt the SOAP content into X.509 ws-security format.
3. Sent new encrypted SOAP content to Webservice.

I have no idea how CF works with Java class files. Has anyone done the same encryption conversion before?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you running? Is the web service setup for Axis 1 or Axis 2?

Comment: Hi Sean Coyne, we are using coldfusion 9. I'm not sure the web service setup as it done by our network team. Any difference for this 2? Is this the possible road cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

In your code to connect to web service, change

```
ws = CreateObject("webservice", [HTTPS URL]);
```

to

```
ws = CreateObject(
  "webservice", 
  "[HTTPS URL]",
  {wsversion="1"}
);
```

in case only Axis 1 works for you.

Also check at the other end, if your using ColdFusion to expose the web service make sure is set up for Axis 1.

Comment: They are using CF9, which defaults to Axis1.  wsversion is only supported in CF10+.

Comment: It's probably at the other end then. Let's see if he can change the exposing web service side.

Comment: Hi Alex Baban, thank for your infor. Will check with the web service vendor tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Alex Baban, Im try adding your code advice, but seem no luck. I think it related to the X.509 WS-security where the SOAP content need to be encrypt before sending to the Webservice,

Comment: I understand that you have ColdFusion 9 as the client so you don't need {wsversion="1"} since ColdFusion 9 only supports Axis1. But what do you have on the server side where the web service is exposed. Is that a ColdFusion server too or is something else? Maybe you can configure that one to use Axis1 somehow.

Comment: Hi Alex Baban, it not cfm server that for sure. I believe it is Java base server as there are some java sample given from the vendor, but i have no working with any java experience at all, it drive me crazy as no CFM sample given. >_<

Comment: If you can, try to get and install a local development version of ColdFusion 2016 which supports Axis 2 by default and make the request with ColdFusion 2016, then at least you eliminate the Axis 1 or Axis 2 problem.

Comment: Hi Alex baban, I dont think so i can run my testing in local PC as it involve SSL setup for both local server and Webservice. Anyway i will check with my network team and vendor to confirm which Axis they used for both server. btw i has try using CFHTTP tag, and it given similar result as cfobject. Perhaps you can have a look for my update on my question?

Comment: Hi Alex Baban, I believe the connection has ready, but some how it showing : [X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement] error message when i sending request to the webservice. It seem related to the WS-Security where my SOAP content need to be encrypted before send it to the webservice. Anyone has similar issue or can guide me how i can fix this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you were provided with a Java class or jar that you need to use to encrypt. I think you should post a new question, and eventually refer some documentation for that web service.